# fetch data from array of foreign keys

Tags: mongodb, collections, promise, fetch

I have two collections in my MongoDB restaurants and dishes ,I'm trying to enter to a specific restaurant and fetch it's dishes according to the foreign keys id in "dishes" array in restaurant object
this is an example how restaurant look like:

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "63a877556959f4b58c5042cf",
        "name": "Claro",
        "chef": "Ran Shmueli",
        "establishYear": 1990,
        "dishes": [
            "63aeb686a8b59bf5aac97702",
            "63aeb923a8b59bf5aac97705",
            "63aeb9d0a8b59bf5aac97708",
            "63aebad9a8b59bf5aac9770b",
            "63aebc8aa8b59bf5aac9770e",
            "63aebe21a8b59bf5aac97711",
            "63aebfafa8b59bf5aac97714",
            "63aec14da8b59bf5aac97717",
            "63aec254a8b59bf5aac9771a"
        ]
    }
]
```

I don't know if I succeed to explain my issue.

I'm expecting to access to dish objects that belongs to specific restaurant and this my fetch function in the front project I don't know what to put in the URL exactly:

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const url = ("http://localhost:3001/api/restaurants/getRestaurants/");
      const response = fetch(url).then((res) =>
        res.json()).then((data) => console.log(data));

      return response;
    }
    catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you add your schema models to the question?

Comment: "*I don't know what to put in the URL exactly*" - we can't tell either, since we don't know how your backend works and what its API is.

Comment: `try`/`catch` around async code (that is not `await`ed) is pointless. Also it's pointless to catch an error only to re-`throw` it. Just remove that entirely. Also your `response` promise always fulfills to `undefined` since that's the return value of `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is with your `.then(data => console.log(data))`. When `console.log` returns `undefined`, `response` becomes a promise that resolves to `undefined` -

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const url = ("http://localhost:3001/api/restaurants/getRestaurants/");
    const response = fetch(url).then((res) =>
      res.json()).then((data) => console.log(data)); // ❌ console.log returns undefined
    return response;
  }
  catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

To fix it, `await` the `fetch` and synchronously `console.log` after `response` is received -

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const url = ("http://localhost:3001/api/restaurants/getRestaurants/");
    const response = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()) // ✅ await
    console.log(response) // ✅
    return response;
  }
  catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Make it a reusable function!

```js
const fetchData = async (url) => { // ✅ url as parameter
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
    console.log(response)
    return response;
  }
  catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

```js
fetchData("http://localhost:3001/api/restaurants/getRestaurants/").then(data => ...)
```

Avoid `catch..throw` anti-pattern! The `try..catch` block is basically pointless as it re-throws whatever error occurs. Allow it to bubble up without catching it -

```js
const fetchData = async (url) => {
  const response = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
  console.log(response)
  return response;
}
```

Remove the `console.log` side effect! You don't want console output for every `fetchData` call. Let's write a `trace` function so we can see the specific data we are interested in -

```js
const fetchData = async (url) => {
  const response = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
  return response; // ✅ zero side effects
}

const trace = x => {
  console.log(x)
  return x
}
```

```js
fetchData(myUrl).then(trace).then(data => ...) // ✅ trace where needed
```

Avoid `async..return..await` anti-pattern! This function does the same exact thing as above -

```js
const fetchData = url => // ✅ async not needed
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json()) // ✅ await not needed
```

```js
fetchData(myUrl).then(trace).then(data => ...) // ✅ works the same!
```

Make `fetchData` more generic! There are times you may wish to change the request type from GET to POST, send a body, or alter the headers of the request -

```js
const fetchData = (url, options = {}) => // ✅ options parameter
  fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json())
```

```js
fetchData(myUrl).then(data => ...) // ✅ without options
fetchData(myUrl, { method: "POST", body: ... }) // ✅ with options
```

Rename it! `fetchData` is ambiguous now. Call it `fetchJson` or perhaps simply `request` -

```js
const request = (url, options = {}) => // ✅ appropriate name
  fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json())
```

```js
request(myUrl).then(trace).then(data => ...) // ✅ clean af
```